# Cambiar tamaño de barra vertical en el sidebar de VSC

Tags: vscode

Existe alguna manera de cambiar el tamaño de la barra vertical del sidebar en Visual Studio Code?

Yo uso  `"editor.scrollbar.verticalScrollbarSize": 4,` para hacer pequeña la barra vertical del editor (lo que se conoce como ascensor también, pero no encuentro una manera de hacerlo también en el sidebar, donde estan todas las carpeta y eso...

Ejemplo:

[image: sidebar de VSC]